# AngularJS form won't submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have this simple HTML form as below  and I am using the Angular js (see the controller. - the is the form is not getting submitted and for some reason I am not able to read the values. i checked online and other questions on Stack overflow, but no success. Any pointers or guidance - what am i missing? thanks in advance :

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="auth">
<head>
    <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" ng-submit="login()" novalidate ng-controller="Login">
        DBID<input type="text" name="dbId" value="23" ng-model="dbId" />
        UserName<input type="text" name="username" value="test@test.com" ng-model="username" />
        Password<input type="text" name="password" value="test1234" ng-model="password" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="login" />
        <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
        <p>The Token is: {{token}}</p>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my AngularJS controller:

```js
var auth = angular.module('auth', []);

    auth.controller('Login', function ($scope, $http)
    {
        $scope.login = function ()
        {
            if ($scope.dbId)
            {
                $scope.list.push(this.dbId);
                $scope.text = '';
            }
        };

        var Credentials = new Object();
        Credentials.DBID = "23";
        Credentials.username = "test@test.com";
        Credentials.password = "test1234";

        $http({
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:55049/api/Security/Login',
            data: Credentials,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic VGVzdEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uVG9rZW46'
            }
        }).then(function (response)
        {
            $scope.token = response.data;
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some modifications to the `JavaScript` code and it's working fine.
Please take a look and run the sample code to see it in action. Also I changed the username, DBID and password to be dynamic with input values.

```js
var auth = angular.module('auth', []);

auth.controller('Login', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.list = [];
 
  $scope.login = function() {
    if ($scope.dbId) {    
     
      $scope.list.push(this.dbId);
      $scope.text = '';

      var Credentials = new Object();
      Credentials.DBID = $scope.dbId;
      Credentials.username = $scope.username;
      Credentials.password = $scope.password;
      
      alert("Posting your data: " + JSON.stringify(Credentials));

      $http({
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:55049/api/Security/Login',
        data: Credentials,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic VGVzdEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uVG9rZW46'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.token = response.data;
      });

    } else {
       alert("Please add DBID");
    }
  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="auth" ng-controller="Login">


  <form method="post" ng-submit="login()" novalidate ng-controller="Login">
    DBID<input type="text" name="dbId" value="23" ng-model="dbId" /> UserName
    <input type="text" name="username" value="test@test.com" ng-model="username" /> Password
    <input type="text" name="password" value="test1234" ng-model="password" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="login" />
    <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
    <p>The Token is: {{token}}</p>
  </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you are closing the login function brace too early. adjusted it and try again.

```js
var auth = angular.module('auth', []);

    auth.controller('Login', function ($scope, $http)
    {
        $scope.login = function ()
        {
            if ($scope.dbId)
            {
                $scope.list.push(this.dbId);
                $scope.text = '';
            }
        

        var Credentials = new Object();
        Credentials.DBID = "23";
        Credentials.username = "test@test.com";
        Credentials.password = "test1234";

        $http({
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:55049/api/Security/Login',
            data: Credentials,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic VGVzdEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uVG9rZW46'
            }
        }).then(function (response)
        {
            $scope.token = response.data;
        });
    };
    });
```

Comment: You are probably right. I tried your new .js and the form still won't submit. Clicking the button does nothing. Very odd. I am new to AngularJS so it is probably something simple I am doing wrong.